# Saving orders in session magento

Tags: database, magento, session

I need to pass an array of unsaved Mage_Sales_Model_Order objects between requests. Tried to save them in checkout/session but they doesn't seem to be saved in DB. Moreover, all data that was added after that to, say, core/session disappears as well. My code:

In model:

```
//$orders is an array of orders
Mage::getSingleton('checkout/session')->setOrders($orders);
Mage::getSingleton('core/session')->setIsMultishipping(true);

// ...
```

In controller:

```
$this->_redirectUrl($url);
```

First I thought that order is not a serializable object so I tried this in interpreter:

```
$serialized = serialize(Mage::getModel('sales/order')->load(1111));
```

and it returned the string as it supposed to. Then I checked if serialized order fits the maximum field size for storing sessions:

```
> echo strlen($serialized);
11465
```

and it's a small value taking into account mediumblob field type for storing session data in the database.

Do you know of any different reasons for Magento to silently fail saving session in the database?

Thanks.

Comment: Unsaved orders are quotes in Magento are they not? Also how are you trying to retrieve the orders?

Comment: Not quite. The problem is that I need to create orders based on current quote and then change it to create a different order, so I prepare orders and save them in the session to save in the database when the customer returns from payment gateway.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I've figured out that it was my fault - the objects my orders were depending on were changed/deleted before orders were saved in the database, so serializing failed silently.